# Get type parameters from generic type argument and use in recursive function call

Tags: scala, generics, recursion, reflection, types

This code is supposed to deserialize a JSON array or JSON object into its respective scala class. The problem I am having is with this line

```
case x if x <:< typeOf[Array[_]] => deserialize[TypeTag[_]](s.getJSONArray(i))'
```

I want the function to detect if the X type argument is an Array of something, and pass that something as the type argument to the recursive function call. 
So if I call `deserialize[Array[Int]](JSONArray)`, it should return an `Array[Array[Int]]`. I need to somehow extract `Int` from `Array[Int]` and pass that to `deserialize[???](JSONArray)`.

```
def deserialize[X: TypeTag](s: JSONObject): X = {
    val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val classType = ru.typeOf[X].typeSymbol.asClass
    val cm = m.reflectClass(classType)
    val constructor = typeTag.tpe.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMethod = cm.reflectConstructor(constructor)

    val params = constructor.asMethod.paramLists.head
    val args = new Array[Any](params.length)

    for(i <- params.indices) {
        val name = params(i).name.decodedName.toString
        println(params(i).typeSignature.toString)
        args(i) = params(i).typeSignature match {
            case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => s.getString(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => s.getInt(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Double] => s.getDouble(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Boolean] => s.getBoolean(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] => s.getLong(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Array[_]] => deserialize[WeakTypeTag[_]](s.getJSONArray(name))
            case t => deserialize[t.type](s.getJSONObject(name))
        }
    }

    constructorMethod(args:_*).asInstanceOf[X]
}

def deserialize[X: ClassTag: TypeTag](s: JSONArray): Array[X] = {
    val arr = new Array[X](s.length())
    for(i <- 0 until s.length) {
        arr(i) = (typeOf[X] match {
            case x if x =:= typeOf[String] => s.getString(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Int] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Double] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Boolean] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Long] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x <:< typeOf[Array[_]] => deserialize[TypeTag[_]](s.getJSONArray(i))
            case x => deserialize[X](s.getJSONObject(i))
        }).asInstanceOf[X]
    }
    arr
}
```

Comment: @Markuse1189
Thanks for the edit. I spent far to long trying to figure out why the backtick formatting would not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

So while I dont quite understand why it works, I was able to hack a working solution together based on a bunch of other stackoverflow questions.

```
def deserialize[X](s: JSONObject)(implicit tTag: TypeTag[X]): X = {
    val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val classType = ru.typeOf[X].typeSymbol.asClass
    val cm = m.reflectClass(classType)
    val constructor = typeTag.tpe.decl(ru.termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorMethod = cm.reflectConstructor(constructor)

    val params = constructor.asMethod.paramLists.head
    val args = new Array[Any](params.length)

    for(i <- params.indices) {
        val name = params(i).name.decodedName.toString
        args(i) = params(i).typeSignature match {
            case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => s.getString(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => s.getInt(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Double] => s.getDouble(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Boolean] => s.getBoolean(name)
            case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] => s.getLong(name)
            case t if t <:< typeOf[Array[_]] => {
                deserialize(s.getJSONArray(name))(getSubInfo(0)(typeToTypeTag(t, m)))
            }
            case t => deserialize(s.getJSONObject(name))(typeToTypeTag(t, m))
        }
    }

    constructorMethod(args:_*).asInstanceOf[X]
}

def deserialize[X](s: JSONArray)(implicit tTag: TypeTag[X]): Array[X] = {
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    implicit val xClassTag = ClassTag[X](mirror.runtimeClass(tTag.tpe))

    val arr = new Array[X](s.length())

    for(i <- 0 until s.length) {
        arr(i) = (typeOf[X] match {
            case x if x =:= typeOf[String] => s.getString(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Int] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Double] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Boolean] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x =:= typeOf[Long] => s.getInt(i)
            case x if x <:< typeOf[Array[_]] => {
                deserialize(s.getJSONArray(i))(getSubInfo[X](0))
            }
            case x => {
                deserialize[X](s.getJSONObject(i))
            }
        }).asInstanceOf[X]
    }
    arr
}

def typeToTypeTag[T](tpe: Type, mirror: reflect.api.Mirror[reflect.runtime.universe.type]): TypeTag[T] = {
    TypeTag(mirror, new reflect.api.TypeCreator {
        def apply[U <: reflect.api.Universe with Singleton](m: reflect.api.Mirror[U]) = {
            assert(m eq mirror, s"TypeTag[$tpe] defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to $m.")
            tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
        }
    })
}

def getSubInfo[X](i: Int)(implicit tTag: TypeTag[X]): TypeTag[_] = {
    typeToTypeTag(tTag.tpe.asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args(i), tTag.mirror)
}
```

The essence of the solution are the last to functions. getSubInfo[X](i: Int) will return a TypeTag for the type parameter at i. So calling getSubInfoArray[Int] will return a TypeTag for Int. typeToTypeTag takes a reflection#type as a parameter and uses black magic to create a typetag.